# How do I pick the best fillet mignon at the supermarket?

Tags: beef, steak

What should I look for when I'm at the store picking out fillet mignon?  How can I tell by look which pieces are more likely to be higher quality pieces of meat?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, fellow Code Reviewer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Marbling

From my experience working in butcher shops, you want to first look for good marbling (unless you are on a low fat diet). To illustrate:

[image: marbling]

I prefer personally anywhere between No. 5 and No. 8. No. 9 and up I find a bit excessive, though some people like it that way. I have had some below No. 5 and they were still good, though.

### Dry-aging

From [Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beef_aging)

> The process changes beef by two means. Firstly, moisture is evaporated from the muscle. This creates a greater concentration of beef flavor and taste. Secondly, the beef’s natural enzymes break down the connective tissue in the muscle, which leads to more tender beef.

Some higher-end butcher shops will dry-age their own beef (at considerable expense) but if you don't have a shop nearby that does that, you can also [dry-age it yourself](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/age-filet-mignon-34888.html).

### Other things

I would recommend not to marinate fillet mignon and season it only lightly. If you plan on wrapping it in bacon, as many do, if you wrap it a day or even a few hours ahead of time the meat will absorb more of the smokiness of the bacon.

Comment: Where would you rate these?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/yx2Wa.jpg

Comment: @nhgrif 3-4 would be my guess.

Comment: That's kind of what we were guessing. They turned out quite tasty though.

Comment: Nice pics, but I have to ask, why wouldn't you salt the steak? Nearly every recipe I've read says to season it when you take it out to warm up (typically with salt & pepper). [These](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7608) two [questions](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11780) seem to agree to salt it up liberally before cooking.

Comment: Salting beef prior to cooking has long been debated. I personally salt beef pretty heavily before I pan sear it, but not when grilling.

Comment: I have removed my statement about salting. It seems to be an old butcher's myth, I've just now changed my mind about it. Source: http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/03/the-food-lab-more-tips-for-perfect-steaks.html